# How to access a folder in Windows 10 from Linux Mint in Hyper-V

Tags: linux-mint, shared-folders, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V as my virtualization agent. Using Hyper-V, I created a Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 32 bit VM using the iso file from [here.](https://www.linuxmint.com/download.php)

On my local machine (Windows 10) I created a folder called **Huge Files** which contains a 10GB file.

Is there a way to get my Linux VM to be able to get access to the content inside my Huge Files folder located on my local machine?

I have looked everywhere and I'm just not making any headway. Also, this is for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to just use the `sftp` [command](http://www.tecmint.com/sftp-command-examples/) in the shell and just `get` the file that I require.